# Strange errors using SneakyInput in my Game

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm following the book over at http://www.cocos2dbook.com, at the moment, I'm making a joystick. Though when I run my game, I get this error on compilation:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SneakyJoystick", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GameplayLayer.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GameplayLayer.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here's my header file:

```
// foundation
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// cocos2D and GameCenter
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>

// Joystick and buttons
#import "SneakyJoystick.h"
#import "SneakyButton.h"

#import "SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase.h"
#import "SneakyButtonSkinnedBase.h"


// sound fx
#import "SimpleAudioEngine.h"

#import "Helpers.h"
#import "GameScene.h"

@interface GameplayLayer : CCLayer {

    // initial player sprite
    CCSprite *player;

    // player health
    int playerStartHealth;

    // joystick
    SneakyJoystick *leftJoystick;

}

@end
```

And my `.m` file (only joystick methods):

```
- (void) initJoystickAndButtons {
    CGSize screen = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;       
    CGRect joystickBaseDimensions = 
    CGRectMake(0, 0, 128.0f, 128.0f);                      
    CGPoint joystickBasePosition;                                  

    joystickBasePosition = ccp(screen.width*0.0625f,
                           screen.height*0.052f);

    SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase *joystickBase =
    [[[SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase alloc] init] autorelease];        
    joystickBase.position = joystickBasePosition;                  
    joystickBase.backgroundSprite = 
        [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"dpadDown.png"];
    joystickBase.thumbSprite = 
        [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"joystickDown.png"];                 // 8
    joystickBase.joystick = [[SneakyJoystick alloc]
                     initWithRect:joystickBaseDimensions]; // 9
    leftJoystick = [joystickBase.joystick retain];                // 10
    [self addChild:joystickBase];
}

- (void) applyJoystick:(SneakyJoystick *)aJoystick toNode:(CCNode *)tempNode forTimeDelta (float)deltaTime {
    CGPoint scaledVelocity = ccpMult(aJoystick.velocity, 1024.0f); // 1

    CGPoint newPosition = 
    ccp(tempNode.position.x + scaledVelocity.x * deltaTime, 
        tempNode.position.y + scaledVelocity.y * deltaTime);       // 2

    [tempNode setPosition:newPosition];                            // 3
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Update Method
- (void) update:(ccTime)deltaTime {
    [self applyJoystick:leftJoystick toNode:player forTimeDelta:deltaTime];
}
```

Comment: Show the relevant code from your project

Comment: It looks like you're building for the wrong target. What os and device are you building for?

Comment: did you add the sneaky input classes to your project? Looks like they're not. PS: if you have problems with this, use Kobold2D (http://www.kobold2d.com) … includes SneakyInput that is ready to use.

Answer (score 1):

These are link errors rather than code errors.  You need to include the files -- either as code or libraries -- that define the missing symbols: SneakyJoystick and SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase.

(I'm not familiar with those features specifically, so I'm not sure if they're supplied in code form or as a .a file.)